# C++ Input Sentence

Tags: c++, input, sentence

I have a problem with inputting sentences to char or string.

```
std::string STabPytania;
bool OK=true;

void pobieranie()
{
    cout << "Podaj ilosc pytan :";
    cin >> iloscP;

    for (pytanie = 1; pytanie <= iloscP; pytanie++)
    {
        cout << "__________________________________________________________";
        cout << "\n Napisz tresc pytania nr" << pytanie << " :";
        std::getline(cin, STabPytania);
        cout << "\n Podaj ilosc odpowiedzi dla: " << pytanie << " pytania:";
        cin >> iloscO;
        for (odpowiedzi = 1; odpowiedzi <= iloscO; odpowiedzi++)
        {
            cout << "\n Napisz tresc odpowiedzi nr" << odpowiedzi << " :";
            cin >> TabOdpowiedzi[pytanie][odpowiedzi];
        }
    }
}
```

But when it comes to asking me for sentence program skips to next instruction without waiting for me input, why?

[Debuging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3bDN.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sedyC.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, only post the text please. Anyway the code in the picture and the code you've posted as text are incomplete. And also non english identifiers make it hard for us to understand your code. Please read this [ask] and this [mcve].

Comment: And for gods sake, do not use native language identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin` some times create issues because of `\n` character in the buffer. So clean that each time with `cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` like below:-

```
void pobieranie()
{
 cout << "Podaj ilosc pytan :";
 cin >> iloscP;
 cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
for (pytanie = 1; pytanie <= iloscP; pytanie++)
{
    cout << "__________________________________________________________";
    cout << "\n Napisz tresc pytania nr" << pytanie << " :";
    std::getline(cin, STabPytania);
    cout << "\n Podaj ilosc odpowiedzi dla: " << pytanie << " pytania:";
    cin >> iloscO;
    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    for (odpowiedzi = 1; odpowiedzi <= iloscO; odpowiedzi++)
    {
        cout << "\n Napisz tresc odpowiedzi nr" << odpowiedzi << " :";
        cin >> TabOdpowiedzi[pytanie][odpowiedzi];
        cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
  }
}
```